# How can i pop the first added item in the stack in Java?

Tags: java

How should i pop not the last added item in a stack but the first added item ? I tried this but just doesn't work. Thank you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Exercise0204 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push("bottom");
        System.out.println(stack);

        stack.push("second");
        System.out.println(stack);

        stack.push("third");
        System.out.println(stack);

        stack.push("fourth");

        System.out.println(stack);

            List list = new ArrayList(stack);

        for (int i = 0; i <stack.size(); i++) {     

            list.remove(i);
        }


    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Change `stack.size()` to `list.size()-1`. That will get rid of the errors.

Comment: Stacks are last-in, first-out. If you want to pop first-in, first-out, then you want a queue. If you want to remove from both ends, use a Deque.

Comment: You're not removing anything from `stack`, you're *trying* to remove elements from `list`. Can you explain more clearly what your goal is?

Comment: 'Pop the first added item' is a contradiction in terms. If you don't want LIFO behaviour, why are you using a stack?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stack data structure doesn't define behaviour for popping of first element. As noted it is a LIFO data structure. Internal implementation details are not relevant(is it a linked list or something else under the hood) here.

I'd rather use java.util.Deque which is Double Ended Queue.

```
Deque<String> deque = new LinkedList<>();

deque.push("S1");
deque.push("S2");
deque.push("S3");
deque.push("S4");
deque.push("S5");
deque.push("S6");
deque.push("S7");
deque.push("S8");

String last = deque.pollLast();
String first = deque.pollFirst();
```

Comment: `Stack` extends `Vector`, which is a proper `List`. That's not an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @shmosel I think I didn't mention java.util.Stack in my response. I meant "Stack" data structure in general.

Comment: I assumed you were responding to the code in the question. I'm not sure what your point is otherwise, considering Java doesn't have a pure LIFO stack.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it if you're stuck with a true stack is to pop everything and immediately push it onto another stack. This will give you a stack with everything in reverse order. Then the top element of the new stack will be the original bottom element.

```java
public E bottomElement(Stack<E> stack) {
    if (stack.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty stack");

    // Flip the stack over.
    final Stack<E> upsideDownStack = new Stack<E>();
    do {
        upsideDownStack.push(stack.pop());
    } while (!stack.isEmpty());

    final E result = upsideDownStack.peek();

    // Flip the stack back over.
    do {
        stack.push(upsideDownStack.pop());
    } while (!upsideDownStack.isEmpty());

    return result;
}
```

If you want to delete the bottom element from the stack rather than only returning it and keeping it in the stack, just change `upsideDownStack.peek()` to `upsideDownStack.pop()` and change the final `do`-`while` loop to a `while` loop.

Answer (score -2):

That is not supposed to work, a stack works on the LIFO principle, which means what comes last goes out first. What you might be looking for is a Queue which works on the FIFO principle

Comment: Java's `Stack` is really a `List`, which supports arbitrary insertion and removal order.